# Difference between value of reg, and adress of reg

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

How is this different?:

```
movl 4(%esp), %eax # put old ptr into eax
9 popl 0(%eax)
```

The first instruction puts content of first arg to `%eax`, but the second does as well (topmost content of stack), or is it indirect adressing? Will not the values overlap each other in `%eax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0(%eax)` is the memory location at the address stored in `eax`.  `%eax` is the content of `eax`.  The two are not equivalent.  Also note that x86 uses a fully-descending stack, so `pop 0(%eax)` is equivalent to

```
mov (%esp), 0(%eax)
add $4, %esp
```

i.e. it loads from `(%esp)` and not `4(%esp)` as your other instruction.  `pop` also changes the value of `esp` which `mov 4(%esp), %eax` does not do.  (do also note that `mov (%esp), 0(%eax)` is not actually a valid instruction, this is just for illustration of the principle).

Answer (score 1):

A register's value/contents can be used in forming a memory address for a read or write (aka a [dereference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)), in what are called [addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode).

`0(%eax)`, and `4(%esp)` are sometimes referred to as a displacement addressing mode (or base + displacement) where the address used for the memory access is the sum of the value in `%eax` with the immediate (here `0`), and the sum of the value in `%esp`  with the immediate `4`, respectively.  Addressing modes can reduce the number of instructions required, since a separate instruction and also temporary register to perform the addition (here, say `%esp` and `4`) is not needed.  The displacement type is one of the most common addressing modes, and is used for access to memory-based local variables and fields (instance variables) of objects, among other things.

---

Registers offer very limited though very fast additional storage beyond memory.  Registers themselves do not have addresses like memory locations; they cannot be indexed or addressed the way that memory can — they can only be named in instructions.  A register can hold a memory address, and used to access memory (dereferenced through an addressing mode), but registers cannot hold register addresses (as there is no such thing).